# How to pass custom user dimension in Google Analytics 4 via VueJS application?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I have a VueJS SPA in which I have user specific information which I want to send in GA once user logged-in as a custom dimension for each and every hit.

I have used [VueGtag](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag) plugin to integrate GA 4 with my SPA.

```
Vue.use(VueGtag, {
    config: {
        id: "G-XXXXXXXXXX" // Data stream measurement ID 
    },
}, router);
```

User scoped custom dimension setup:

[image]

`vue-gtag` plugin provides a way to send custom dimensions via [customMap](https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/methods/custommap) like below **:**

```
this.$gtag.customMap({ 'dimension2': 'age' })
this.$gtag.event('age_dimension', { age: 35 })
```

Also tried as per the [gtag documentaion for GA4](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10271001#analyticsjs-custom-dimensions-metrics):

```
this.$gtag.query('set', { dimension2: 'age' })
this.$gtag.event('age_dimension', { age: 35 })
```

With above mentioned approaches. I can see the event data in Realtime but it is showing (not set) if looking in `Engagement` tab along with some other class. For Ex: `Pages and Screens`.

[image]

Comment: The "age" dimensions in User scope from your "user scoped custom dimension setup" could be tagged by `this.$gtag.query('set', 'user_properties', { age_dimension: '35' })`.

You have this tagging example: `this.$gtag.event('age_dimension', { age: 35 })`. This tagging specifies the event name is `age_dimension`, the event parameter is `age`, and the event parameter `age`'s value is 35.

Comment: @Brett Its not working i tried that.

Comment: @Brett It is giving this error `Argument of type "set" is not assignable to parameter of type "event"` on using `this.$gtag.query('set', 'user_properties', { age_dimension: '35' })`

Answer (score 2):

User-specific information is best tagged by creating a user-property in tagging. In GA4 reporting, a user-property is reported as a User-scoped custom dimension (Learn more about [Custom dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209) in GA4).

Here's an example of tagging a `user_location` user-property via gtag.js in GA4 on [Optimize Smart's GA4 User Properties Tutorial](https://www.optimizesmart.com/how-to-create-and-use-user-properties-in-ga4/#6-adding-the-user-property-to-your-website-via-gtagjs-).

Here's an example of tagging a `favorite_composer`, `favorite_instrument`, and `season_ticketholder` user-properties via gtag.js in GA4 on [Tips for upgrading from analytics.js to gtag.js](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10271001#analyticsjs-custom-dimensions-metrics).

The `vue-gtag` gives full access to gtag API via the `query` method ([vue-gtag's reference on query](https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/query)). If `favorite_composer` is the "user specific information which I want to send in GA once user logged-in as a custom dimension for each and every hit", you can accomplish that with code similar to:

```
this.$gtag.query('set', 'user_properties', {
        favorite_composer: 'Mahler'
      })
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Solution provided by you is not working. By mistake I gave bounty to your answer.

Comment: Getting this error while trying to use the gtag.query ` Argument of type '"set"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"event"'`